# Init Actions causing Jupyterhub internal error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, jupyterhub

I have a dag creating a Dataproc Cluster with Jupyter and Anaconda as additional components, I start the cluster with a custom script to install Python packages.

```
class CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(DataprocClusterCreateOperator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _build_cluster_data(self):
        cluster_data = super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self)._build_cluster_data()
        cluster_data['config']['endpointConfig'] = {
            'enableHttpPortAccess': True
        }
        cluster_data['config']['softwareConfig']['optionalComponents'] = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]
        return cluster_data

create_cluster=CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(
            task_id='create-%s-%s' % (cluster_name, user), 
            cluster_name='%s-%s' % (cluster_name, user),
            project_id=project_id,
            num_workers=2,
            num_masters=2,
            master_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
            worker_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
            subnetwork_uri='projects/XXX-network/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/prod',
            init_actions_uris=['gs://XXX/python-packages.sh'],
            master_disk_size=1000,
            worker_disk_size=1000,
            master_disk_type='pd-ssd',
            worker_disk_type='pd-ssd',
            storage_bucket=XXX, 
            region='europe-west1', 
            zone='europe-west1-b',
            auto_delete_ttl=36000, 
            dag=dag
        )
```

Here is the `python-package.sh`script

```
#!/bin/sh
apt update
apt install python-pip -y
apt install libpq-dev python-dev
pip install -U google-cloud-storage
pip install -U xlrd 
pip install -U gcsfs
pip install -U tensorflow
pip install -U pymongo
pip install -U openpyxl
pip install -U psycopg2
```

It used to work just fine but since Friday, the cluster is launching but there is an 500 Internal Error when accessing the Jupyterhub. 
I have connected to the master and I do have access to the bucket (doing `gsutil cat gs://XXX/python-packages.sh`) and the initialization script was correctly saved in `/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0`. I did not find any error in `/var/log/jupyter_notebook.log` so I am a bit out of ideas right now.

Removing the `init_actions` does make the Jupyterhub works again but I do need these packages

Comment: Which Dataproc image version are you using? As a workaround, you can pin the version to an old version that worked for you, e.g. `1.4.25-debian9`.

Comment: Yes it did the trick, I think this is a version package issue but I cannot figure out which one

Comment: Can you follow this doc to install pip packages? I guess the pip you installed in the your unit action is not compatible with the cluster's pip. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration

Comment: Which Dataproc version are you using? I tried to reproduce the problem with 1.4, but the init actions failed `+ pip install -U tensorflow, ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall`.
`